# R: Dynamically referencing and operating on variables in data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am trying to dynamically reference and perform operations on a vector in a data frame. I've tried various forms of `eval`, `parse`, and so on, but they either return the string I provide or throw errors. Someone has a solution? As I propose In the psuedo-code below, the solution is presumably to replace DO_SOMETHING() with some other functions.

```
# Example data
mydat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10))

# Function to add 5 to specified variable in a data frame
add5 <- function(data, var){
                 var_ref <- paste0("data$", var)
                 out <- DO_SOMETHING(var_ref) + 5
                 return out
        }

add5(mydat,x) // returns a numeric vector value of 5
class(add5(mydat,x)) // numeric
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass unquoted column names, you could use `deparse` `substitute` like :

```
add5 <- function(data, var){
   out <- data[deparse(substitute(var))] + 5
   return(out)
}

add5(mydat,x)
```

---

Using `dplyr` and some non-standard evaluation with curly-curly we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

add5 <- function(data, var){
   data %>% mutate(out = {{var}} + 5)
}

add5(mydat, x)
#         x  out
#1   1.1604 6.16
#2   0.7002 5.70
#3   1.5868 6.59
#4   0.5585 5.56
#5  -1.2766 3.72
#6  -0.5733 4.43
#7  -1.2246 3.78
#8  -0.4734 4.53
#9  -0.6204 4.38
#10  0.0421 5.04
```

Comment: The first solution does not work with my data. In my more complex case, my function looks something like function(data, t1, t2){ var <- paste0("foo",t1,t2); ...) where the value of var is assigned within the function rom arguments t1 and t2. Using the same code led to "Error: Can't find column var in .data." When I replaced var within data[deparse(substitute(var))] with  paste0("foo",t1,t2), I receive the same type of error. It's only when I use the unquoted value of  paste0("foo",t1,t2) that it works. The solution is to wrap get() around deparse() . You might add this to your solution.

Comment: I am not sure how you are using this in your function but things behave differently based on your input. The solution differs if you want to pass unquoted variable (like `x`) or quoted variables (like "x"). If you are passing unquoted variable to subset a column based on name you need `data[deparse(substitute(var))]` but if you are passing quoted variable you don't need `deparse` and `substitute`. You can directly do `data[var]`.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, unquoting argument names is easy. If you start writing functions using variable names, I recommend you to use `data.table` (see [a blog post I wrote on the subject](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/)).

With one variable you will use `get` to unquote variable name

```r
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(x = rnorm(10))
myvar <- "x"
data[, out := get(myvar) + 5]

data
              x      out
 1: -0.30229987 4.697700
 2:  0.51658585 5.516586
 3:  0.12180432 5.121804
 4:  1.53438805 6.534388
 5:  0.06213513 5.062135
 6:  0.17935070 5.179351
 7:  0.70002065 5.700021
 8:  0.12067590 5.120676
 9: -0.41002931 4.589971
10:  0.45385072 5.453851
```

Note that I don't need to reassign result because `:=` updates by reference.

With several variables, you will use `.SD` + `lapply`. This syntax means apply something over the *Subset of Data* (.SD). `.SDcols` argument is used to control what are the columns considered in the subset of data.

This is a very general approach that works in many situations.

```r
data <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
data[, c('out1','out2') := lapply(.SD, function(x) return(x + 5)), .SDcols = c("x","y")]
data
              x          y     out1     out2
 1:  0.91187875 -0.2010539 5.911879 4.798946
 2: -0.70906903  0.2074829 4.290931 5.207483
 3: -0.52517961  0.2027444 4.474820 5.202744
 4:  0.09967933 -1.2315601 5.099679 3.768440
 5: -0.40392510 -0.1777705 4.596075 4.822229
 6:  0.65891623  0.2394889 5.658916 5.239489
 7:  0.76275090  1.5695957 5.762751 6.569596
 8: -0.52395704 -0.7083462 4.476043 4.291654
 9:  0.52728890 -1.1308284 5.527289 3.869172
10: -1.00418691 -0.5569468 3.995813 4.443053
```

I could have used this approach with one column (.SDcols = 'x').